# How to close an FMX TFrame shown in a TPopup from event handlers inside the TFrame

Tags: delphi, popup, modal-dialog, frame, firemonkey

I use a frame that is shown by calling `TPopup.Popup(true);` method. If the frame contains a button with the `ModalResult` property set (to, for example, mrOK) it closes automatically when clicked by the user. But I need to close the frame in an `OnClick` event of a `TListBox` in it.
Frame does not have Close method. 
I would like to avoid using message posting to the parent form as it might cause future problems when the application is ported to Android as well as I would prefer not to declare the `OnClick` event handler for the `Frame.ListBox` in the parent Form because the frame might be shown by several different forms and it will worsen the quality of parent Form code making it heavy and difficult to read.
I would highly appreciate suggestions how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following way out. I call

```
(GetParentComponent as TPopup).IsOpen:=false;
```

Comment: The reason a frame has no close method is because it is not a form. It is not the frame that closes automatically it is the form that contains it (in this case a TPopup). That is also why your fix works. (Despite appearances, frames are more like components than forms)

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from TPopUp like explained here ([How to make my own dialog component from Firemonkey TPopUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112161/how-to-make-my-own-dialog-component-from-firemonkey-tpopup)) then you can call `ClosePopup` when an event is trigerred in your frame.